# Can i put this function in localstorage and get it back to the page after refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm using React and I want to put the result of this function in the localstorage so it can persist in the page after reload.

```
createNewField(key){

 this.setState({
   [key] : this.state[key].concat({...this.state.templates.empty[key], id: uniqid()}),
  })

 }
```

Is it possible to create a new field and make it back to the page after reload with the same function or do i need another function for that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The "result of this function" is undefined. Do you mean you want to put the same thing you're setting state to into local storage? I mean... `createNewField` can do whatever it wants--what's the specific issue?

Comment: I mean everytime i'm creating a newField, i want it back in the page as it uploads.

Comment: What is a “new field”? What is preventing you from adding a value to local storage here? What specifically do you want in local storage that you’re unable to add?

Comment: The new field is the value of an input that's going to be add in a form. I don't know how / where I need to put my localstorage.setItem / localstorage.getItem in this function.